# How to restore mongodb backup into a new instance?

Tags: mongorestore

I have a tgz file and I extracted it into a folder, there was a lot of gz files then I extracted them too, now I have a folder with some bson and json files.
I Installed mongod v4.2.14 on a debian machine and after that I do nothing to db just connected to it for the first time.
Please help me to restore this folder into this instance. my problem is that when I use mongorestore without authentication it gives me error and I know that in mongodb we dont have a global username and pasword, I dont know what to place in -u and -p ?

'mongorestore -u WHAT!!! -p WHAT!!! --authenticationDatabase admin -d zaer_db ./zaer_db2
'

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I created a db before and setup a password for it. I reinstalled linux and reinstalled mongodb and mongorestore worked fine without password.